# Making a Bokeh Heat map with a 20 x 1000 numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, plot, heatmap, bokeh

My Goal is to make a heat map like this one [image: bokeh heatmap]

The only difference is my array is much larger 30x3000. It seems like bokeh should be able to handle something like this but when I try I get something that looks like this: [image: my version with large numpy array].

If I zoom in a lot I can start to see the color coding but I would like it to not look like that at first pass.

I am new to Bokeh but it seems like something quite trivial. I usually use imshow in python. But, am trying to switch over.

EDIT: Here is the code:

```
from bokeh._legacy_charts import HeatMap, output_file, show

xyvalues = np.random.random((28,1000))

df = pd.DataFrame(xyvalues)

output_file('heatmap.html')

hm = HeatMap(df)

show(hm)
```

Comment: You will need to show us the code that produced your plot.

Comment: @wflynny The code has been edited in. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heat map gives you a single "cell" for each of your categories. If you have 3000 categories and your plot is 1000px wide, that makes each cell less than 1px wide.

If I make your bokeh plot very wide by setting width `hm = HeatMap(df, width=3000)`then I can see colors immediately.

[image]

In Bokeh, [`ImageRGBA`](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#images) is more similar to `imshow`.